# Vuejs fix date from date received from php server

Tags: php, vue.js, date, datetime

I have a datetime object received from server in the following format:

```
{"date":"2021-05-11 13:02:01.273000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"}
```

I'm having trouble to get the correct date corresponding to the user browser how can I parse this date into a js date object with the right time zone calculations. I used to take only the date disregarding the time zone and it turned out to be wrong to the user

Comment: Try giving this a look [How to initialize a JavaScript Date to a particular time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-a-particular-time-zone)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `toLocaleString` method and specify the `timeZone`:

```js
x = JSON.parse(`{"date":"2021-05-11 13:02:01.273000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"}`);
new Date(x.date).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: x.timezone})
```